# How to use Reflection in factory design patterns in C# .Net core

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, reflection, .net-core

I've implementing the Factory Method in c# .Net core in the following way.I have several concrete products let's say `Gateway1` and `Gateway2`

```
public interface IGateway
{
    void Test();
}
```

**ConcreteCreator:**

```
public class PaymentFactory
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;
    private readonly IPaymentGatewayRepository _paymentGatewayRepository;

    public PaymentFactory(IPaymentTransactionRepository paymentTransactionRepository,
        IPaymentGatewayRepository paymentGatewayRepository)
    {
        _paymentTransactionRepository = paymentTransactionRepository;
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
    }

    public IGateway ExecuteCreation(string bank)
    {
        switch (bank)
        {
            case "Gateway1":
                {
                    return new Gateway1(_paymentGatewayRepository);
                }
            case "Gateway2":
                {
                    return new Gateway2(_paymentTransactionRepository, _paymentGatewayRepository);

                }
            default:
                {
                    return null;

                }
        }
    }

}
```

**ConcreteProducts:**

```
public class Gateway1 : IGateway
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;

    public Gateway1(IPaymentTransactionRepository paymentGatewayRepository)
    {
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class Gateway2 : IGateway
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;
    private readonly IPaymentGatewayRepository _paymentGatewayRepository;

    public Gateway2(IPaymentTransactionRepository paymentGatewayRepository,
        IPaymentGatewayRepository paymentGatewayRepository)
    {
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

This code is running but I want to make two changes to it.

1- How to implementing the Factory Method by Reflection?

2- How to pass in multiple parameters to Create `ConcreteProducts`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use bellow code.You need to change the `PaymentFactory` as follows.
you can user **IServiceProvider** Injection of the service into the constructor of the class where it's used.

ConcreteProducts Names:

```
public enum PaymentGatewayEnum
{
    Gateway1 = 1,
    Gateway2 = 2,
}
```

then PaymentFactory:

```
public class PaymentFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public PaymentFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IGateway ExecuteCreation(PaymentGatewayEnum bank)
    {
        var services = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => typeof(IGateway).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Name, bank.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        return Activator.CreateInstance(services, _serviceProvider) as IGateway;
    }

}
```

and then:

```
public class Gateway1 : IGateway
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;

    public Gateway1(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _paymentTransactionRepository = (IPaymentTransactionRepository)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPaymentTransactionRepository));
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class Gateway2 : IGateway
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;
    private readonly IPaymentGatewayRepository _paymentGatewayRepository;

    public Gateway2(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _paymentTransactionRepository = (IPaymentTransactionRepository)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPaymentTransactionRepository));
        _paymentGatewayRepository = (IPaymentGatewayRepository)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPaymentGatewayRepository));
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Reza Jenabi's solution is the following:

Enum to select between gateways:

```
public enum PaymentGatewayType
{
    GATEWAY1,
    GATEWAY2,
}
```

The factory interface:

```
public interface IPaymentFactory
{
}
```

The factory, which can be registered as a singleton:

```
public class PaymentFactory : IPaymentFactory
{
    private Dictionary<PaymentGatewayType, Func<IGateway>> GatewayTypes 
       = new Dictionary<PaymentGatewayType, Func<IGateway>>();

    public PaymentFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Gateways = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(IGateway).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract)
            .Select(t => new Func<IGateway>(() => 
                 ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, t) as IGateway))
            .ToDictionary(f => f().GatewayType);
    }

    public IGateway GetGateway(PaymentGatewayType gatewayType)
    {
        return GatewayTypes[gatewayType]();
    }
}
```

The gateways:

```
public interface IGateway
{
    //The GatewayType property is important as that's what the PaymentFactory uses
    // as a discriminator (see .ToDictionary(f => f().GatewayType);)
    PaymentGatewayType GatewayType{ get; }
    void Test();
}

public class Gateway1 : IGateway
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;

    //Here we override the GatewayType property in the interface to set which 
    //gateway this class belongs to
    public override PaymentGatewayType GatewayType => PaymentGatewayType.GATEWAY1;

    public Gateway1(IPaymentTransactionRepository paymentGatewayRepository)
    {
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //code
    }
}

public class Gateway2 : IGateway
{
    private readonly IPaymentTransactionRepository _paymentTransactionRepository;
    private readonly IPaymentGatewayRepository _paymentGatewayRepository;

    //Here we override the GatewayType property in the interface to set which 
    //gateway this class belongs to
    public override PaymentGatewayType GatewayType => PaymentGatewayType.GATEWAY2;

    public Gateway2(IPaymentTransactionRepository paymentGatewayRepository,
        IPaymentGatewayRepository paymentGatewayRepository)
    {
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
        _paymentGatewayRepository = paymentGatewayRepository;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Then in the calling code something like the following:

```
public class GatewayService
{
    private readonly IPaymentFactory _paymentFactory;

    public GatewayService(IPaymentFactory paymentFactory)
    {
        _paymentFactory = paymentFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething(PaymentGatewayType gatewayType)
    {
        IGateway gateway = _paymentFactory.GetGateway(gatewayType);

        gateway.Test();
    }
}
```

To add more Gateways simply add a new enum Value, e.g. GATEWAY3 and create a new Gateway3 class that inherits from IGateway.